# Addition and subtraction formula for arctangents?

Tags: trigonometry

Could someone help me to decompose the argument of these functions? I was searching online but couldn't find it:

$\arctan(x + y) = $ ?

$\arctan(x - y) = $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition:
$$\arctan(x) + \arctan(y) 
= \arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$$

Subtraction:
$$\arctan(x) - \arctan(y) 
= \arctan\left(\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right)$$

Comment: What is your symbol as superscipt on the tangent? In any case, this answer would certainly benefit from some MathJax/LaTeX formatting...